# create a generic regex for a string in perl

Tags: perl

I have tried to create regex for the below:

```
STRING sou_u02_mlpv0747_CCF_ASB001_LU_FW_ALERT|/opt/app/medvhs/mvs/applications/cm_vm5/fwhome/UnifiedLogging|UL_\d{8}_CCF_ASB001_LU_sou_u02_mlpv0747_Primary.log.csv|FATAL|red|1h||fw_alert

REGEX----> /^[^#]\w+\|[^\|]+\|\w+\|\w+\|\w*\|\w*\|([^\|]+|)\|\w*$/
```

I am unable to figure out the mistake here.

I created the above by referring another regex which working fine and given below

```
/^[^#]\w+\|[^\|]+\|([^\|]+|)\|[rm]\|(in|out|old|new|arch|missing)\|\w+\|([0-9-,]+|)\|\w*\|\w*$/

sou_u02_mlpv0747_CCF_ASB001_LU_ODR|/opt/app/medvhs/mvs/applications/cm_vm5/components/CCF_ASB001_LU/SPOOL/ODR||r|out|30m|0400-1959|30m|gprs_in_stag
```

can some one please help me. Any leads would be highly apprciated.

Comment: I tried formatting your question, but it's very hard to understand what's going on there. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and look at [mcve] if you want people to help you. Then [edit] your question, fix your typos and make the data and code more readable. It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to capture any of the fields in this data? Or do you just want to match to see if your line (in possibly a log file) is relevant? If you want the individual fields, why not `split` them and then check individually?

Comment: The regex which is "_working fine_" has `(in|out|old|new|arch|missing)` but none of these words are in the shown string.  (While this is indeed very hard to read).  Can you state what you need to capture from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from a brief look at your source text (the first that you included).

It is composed of "sections" separated with `|` char.

This char (`|`) must be matched by `\|`. Remember about the preceding
backslash, otherwise, a "bare" `|` would mean the **alternative separator**
(you used it in one place).

And now take a look at each section (between `|`):

- Some of them contain only a sequence of **word chars** (and can be matched
  by `\w+`).
- Other sections, however, contain also **other chars**, e.g. slashes,
  backslash, braces and dots, so each such section is actually a sequence
  of chars **other than "|"** and must be matched by `[^|]+` (here,
  between `[` and `]`, the vertical bar may be unescaped).

Now let's write each section and its "type":

1. `sou_u02_..._FW_ALERT` - word chars.
2. `/opt/app/.../UnifiedLogging` - other chars (because of slashes).
3. `UL_\d{8}_..._Primary.log.csv` - other chars (because of `\d{8}`
    and dots).
4. `FATAL|red|1h` - 3 sections composed of word chars.
5. An **empty** section, between 2 consecutive `|` chars.
6. `fw_alert` - word chars.

And now, how to match these groups, and the separating `|`:

- Point 1: `\w+\|` - word chars and (escaped) vertical bar.
- Point 2 and 3 (together): `(?:[^|]+\|){2}` - a non-capturing
  group - `(?:...)`, containing a sequence of "other" chars - `[^|]+`
  and a vertical bar - `\|`, occurring 2 times `{2}`.
- Point 4 (three "word char" groups): `(?:\w+\|){3}` - similiar to
  the previous point.
- Point 5: Just as in your solution - `([^|]+|)\|`, a capturing group -
  `(...)`, with 2 alternatives `...|...`. The first alternative is
  `[^|]+` (a sequence of "other" chars), and the second alternative
  is empty. After the capturing group there is `\|` to match the vertical
  bar.
- Point 6: `\w+` - word chars. This time no `\|`, as this is the last
  section.

The regex assembled so far must be:

- prepended with a `^` (start of string) and
- appended with a `$` (end of string).

So the whole regex, matching your source text can be:

```
^\w+\|(?:[^|]+\|){2}(?:\w+\|){3}([^|]+|)\|\w+$
```

Actually, the only capturing group can be written another way,
as `([^|]*)` - without alternatives, but with `*` as the
repetition count, allowing also empty content.
Your choice, which variant to apply.

Comment: Can't look carefully now, but `[^|]` will also scoop up ``\`` from `\|` -- if it ever bumps into it.  It may be safer to spell out non-word chars that should also be matched, with `[\w.\/]` (etc)

Answer (score 0):

The third field

```
UL_\d{8}_CCF_ASB001_LU_sou_u02_mlpv0747_Primary.log.csv
```

Contains a backslash, `\`, braces `{` `}` and dots `.`. None of these can be matched by `\w`

Note also that there is no need to escape a pipe `|` inside a characters class: `[^|]+` is fine